# question to remap keys in Ubuntu terminal to Mac has not worked for me yet in Ubuntu VM under parallels

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mac

After looking here for answers I am still struggling. I am running Ubuntu 21.04 as a virtual machine on my M1 Mac mini under Parallels 16. I am also running Windows 10 as a VM and the keys there map fine to my Mac keyboard, but under the Ubuntu terminal, some keys are messed up. Not all of them. Here is the layout for the Ubuntu terminal:

```
   q w d f k j u r l ;
   a s e t g y n i o h
   z x c v b p m , . /
```

The Mac keyboard is:

```
   q w e r t y u i o p
   a s d f g h j k l ;
   z x c v b n m , . /
```

The numbers and the rest of the keys are all the same.
Can someone help me? I have tried several possible answers found here and still, none have worked. And what makes it more difficult is that I have to type in all solutions in this odd keyboard layout. Please help

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, your Ubuntu is set to Norman keyboard layout or your Mac is. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` select what you need, perhaps US - Apple keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Never got an answer to my question that worked, but guess what? I updated Ubuntu and it stopped working. It said that no video controller was available or something to that effect. After trying to work on that problem, today I decided to just delete that VM from Parallels and reinstalled it and guess what? Now the keyboard on terminal in Ubuntu is the same as in the Mac! Wala!! fixed itself !!!

Thanks anyway for your help to those that responded. It's appreciated.